# Re establishing clients connection with WCF service

Tags: wpf, wcf, service, connection, client

I have a WPF application which communicates with a WCF service which provides data that is updated by WPF application on its UI on continues basis. The Service is hosted on netTCP. Now, if for some reason the WCF app loses its LAN connection and after a few seconds the connection is established again, the WPF app is not able to resume its connection with the service.
Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a socket on the WPF client, which will accept a connection from the service, then if the service is back online again it sends a data packet to everyone in the collection currently connected, then if the client recieves a packet it requests a connection with the service again, which will "resume" the connection